# How do I write two arrays to a ".dat"file within python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to print two arrays side by side in columns to a '.dat' file. Here is my code:

```
rc=[1,2,3]
vc=[3,2,1]
dat = np.array([rc, vc])
a= np.column_stack((dat))
e= "There are 3 elements in this array"
hdrtxt='# rc in AU','#vc in km/s'
np.savetxt('jb_vfreefall.dat', a, delimiter=',',header=e,hdrtxt )
```

I am hoping to get the file to look like this:

"There are 3 elements in this array"

```
#rc in AU    #vc in km/s

  1               3

  2               2

  3               1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I will tailor my future questions better. However, if you have any information to help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have both `e` as a header and `hdrtxt` as a header, choose one.

If you want to use `hdrtxt` you should modify it from:

```
hdrtxt='# rc in AU','#vc in km/s'
```

to:

```
hdrtxt='# rc in AU, #vc in km/s'
```

when I call with:

```
hdrtxt='# rc in AU, #vc in km/s'
np.savetxt('jb_vfreefall.dat', a, delimiter=',', header=hdrtxt)
```

The file look like:

```
# # rc in AU, #vc in km/s
1.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00
```

Read more about [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)